# Instalação silenciosa do Postgres e criação da base em instalador

Tags: c#, winforms, postgresql, instalador

Como eu posso embutir o banco de dados PostgreSQL no instalador do meu sistema WinForms?

Eu até consigo colocar ele como pré-requisito para instalar antes dos binários do sistema, no entanto, eu queria fazer uma instalação silenciosa. Também gostaria de saber como faço para criar o banco da minha aplicação durante a instalação.

Comment: Como é feito a instalação do seu sistema? Como você criou este instalador, qual ferramenta usou, etc.?

Comment: Tenho os arquivos binários do meu sistema, tenho o instalador do postgreSQL na versão 9.5, primeiro eu tentei usar o programa **Advanced Installer** disponível nesse site http://www.advancedinstaller.com/ . Nele eu consegui adicionar pré-requisitos à instalação do meu software, aí pedi para ele instalar o Postgre antes de instalar o sistema, caso contrário a instalação não poderia continuar, até aí tudo bem, o problema de instalar o banco do sistema foi resolvido, no entanto fica ainda o desafio de criar o banco de dados, e fazer com que toda a instalação do exe do postgre seja em modo oculto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você chamar o executável do postgresql passando como parâmetro --help vai abrir as informações:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você deverá informar a senha, o path da instalação, isso você pode definir através dos parâmetros.

Então você pode chamar deste jeito:

```
msiexec /i postgresql[versão].msi  /qr INTERNALLAUNCH=1 ADDLOCAL=server,psql,docs SERVICEDOMAIN="%COMPUTERNAME%"
        SERVICEPASSWORD="SecretWindowsPassword123" SUPERPASSWORD="VerySecret" BASEDIR="c:\postgres" TRANSFORMS=:lang_de
```

OBS: Nunca usei o Advanced Installer, mas já utilizei o [NSIS Compiler](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), e atualmente uso o [Inno Setup Compiler](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), sei que da para fazer isto sem problemas..

Referência: [link](http://pginstaller.projects.pgfoundry.org/silent.html)

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: E para rodar o script do banco também é possível amigo?

Comment: Sim, basta ir no path da instalação /bin/psql.exe, e passar o parâmetro --help também vai listar os parâmetros disponíveis, mas basicamente você deve fazer isto: `psql.exe –U [usuario] -w –d [nome do banco] –f [path script]`